# Orion Context Broker works half of the times

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I've installed Orion Context Broker 0.23.0 and it behaves rare: it only works half of the times. For instance, when trying to retrieve the version I get this error message:

```
$ curl "http://localhost:1026/version"
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
$ curl "http://localhost:1026/version"
<orion>
  <version>0.23.0</version>
  <uptime>15 d, 22 h, 13 m, 18 s</uptime>
  <git_hash>f5d76a6f11736d52402e63a4aa0ba990bff7f5eb</git_hash>
  <compile_time>Fri Jul 10 13:21:42 CEST 2015</compile_time>
  <compiled_by>fermin</compiled_by>
  <compiled_in>centollo</compiled_in>
</orion>
$ curl "http://localhost:1026/version"
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
$ curl "http://localhost:1026/version"
<orion>
  <version>0.23.0</version>
  <uptime>15 d, 22 h, 13 m, 53 s</uptime>
  <git_hash>f5d76a6f11736d52402e63a4aa0ba990bff7f5eb</git_hash>
  <compile_time>Fri Jul 10 13:21:42 CEST 2015</compile_time>
  <compiled_by>fermin</compiled_by>
  <compiled_in>centollo</compiled_in>
</orion>
```

This behaviour is deterministic, I mean, after failing it always works, and after working it always fails. This occurs with all the operations within the REST API.

I've checked the listening ports and the process running them matches the Orion's one:

```
$ sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 1026
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1026                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9944/contextBroker  
tcp        0      0 :::1026                     :::*                        LISTEN      9944/contextBroker

$ ps ax | grep contextBroker | grep -v grep
 9944 ?        Ssl    0:13 /usr/bin/contextBroker -port 1026 -logDir /var/log/contextBroker -pidpath /var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid -dbhost localhost -db orion -multiservice
```

Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orion runs by default listening to IPv4 and IPv6. We have found that in cases similar to the ones you described disabling IPv6 solves the problem (we don't know yet the exact cause, maybe is related with the operating system or it is involved is some way...).

Tu run Orion in only-IPv4 mode you have to use the `-ipv4` option either in the contextBroker command line or (if you are running Orion as a service) editing the `/etc/sysconfig/contextBroker` file to add `-ipv4` to the BROKER_EXTRA_OPS variable (have a look to [the documentation](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion#configuration-file) for more information about configuring Orion as a service). After modifying `/etc/sysconfig/contextBroker` you have to restart Orion using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/contextBroker restart
```

Comment: Hello, I am having the same behaviour with contextBroker 0.24 that I've installed these days on our servers. It's in a CentOS 6.7 machine after installing mongo-server, mongo-shell and cygnus. Tomcat and CEP are also installed.
The option line `BROKER_EXTRA_OPS="-ipv6"` on the mentioned file didn't solve the issue, even after several trials and reboots.
Should I post a question of it's own?

Comment: Actually, it should be `BROKER_EXTRA_OPS="-ipv4"` (4, not 6). Could you test that way and check if it works, please?

Comment: You're right. My mistake when typing the comment. I copied that line direclty from the file and was with the last configuration I tested. Indeed "-ipv4" doesn't work either.
What I did notice meanwhile, is that this only happens if Apache Tomcat 7 (with Java jdk 8 installed) is running. If I stop Tomcat, Orion behaves well.
Thing is, I need both to run, because CEP GE runs on Tomcat.

Comment: Thus it seems to be a different problem, caused by some kind of Orion-Tomcat interference. I'd suggest to open a new question to deal with it (although you could include a link to this question as a reference).