# Context Broker only responds when asked twice

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

So the problem is that when i try to establish a connection with the Context Broker whether i'm trying to update the entity or read the values. It only responds ok when i ask a second time.

Context Broker Version: 0.24.0 (i updated from 0.20.0 because i thought that was the problem)

Example:

```
python2.7 GetEntity.py entity_1
```

Output:

```
* Asking to http://188.***.**.***:1026/ngsi10/queryContext
* Headers: {'Fiware-Service': 'fiwarefinal', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json', 'X-Auth-Token': 'NULL'}
* Sending PAYLOAD:
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "",
            "id": "entity_1",
            "isPattern": "false"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": []
}

...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GetEntity.py", line 73, in <module>
    r = requests.post(URL, data=PAYLOAD, headers=HEADERS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 109, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

When i do it a second time:

```
* Asking to http://188.***.**.***:1026/ngsi10/queryContext
* Headers: {'Fiware-Service': 'fiwarefinal', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json', 'X-Auth-Token': 'NULL'}
* Sending PAYLOAD:
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "",
            "id": "entity_1",
            "isPattern": "false"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": []
}

...

* Status Code: 200
* Response:
{
  "contextResponses" : [
    {
      "contextElement" : {
        "type" : "",
        "isPattern" : "false",
        "id" : "entity_1",
        "attributes" : [
          {
            "name" : "humidity",
            "type" : "int",
            "value" : "4"
          },
          {
            "name" : "latitude",
            "type" : "float",
            "value" : "3"
          },
          {
            "name" : "longitude",
            "type" : "float",
            "value" : "5"
          },
          {
            "name" : "temperature",
            "type" : "int",
            "value" : "8"
          }
        ]
      },
      "statusCode" : {
        "code" : "200",
        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Example Nrº 2:

```
curl http://188.***.**.***:1026/version
```

Output:

```
curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

And when i do it a second time:

```
<orion>
  <version>0.24.0</version>
  <uptime>0 d, 0 h, 41 m, 27 s</uptime>
  <git_hash><deleted for safety reasons></git_hash>
  <compile_time>Mon Sep 14 17:52:44 CEST 2015</compile_time>
  <compiled_by>fermin</compiled_by>
  <compiled_in>centollo</compiled_in>
</orion>
```

Sometimes i even have to restart because when i check the status of the Context Broker it gives me an error. I'm not sure of the error but i think it's something like "the pid file doesn't exist"

**EDIT:**

[image: Error COntext Broker]

**EDIT 2:**

So i tried using the script from Fiware-Figway:

python2.7 GetEntity.py entity_1

and as expected because of the problem, it worked half the times.

Full log trace for the Context Broker:

```
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.269EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=main | comp=Orion | msg=contextBroker.cpp[1509]: Orion Context Broker is running
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.280EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=mongoConnect | comp=Orion | msg=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[196]: Successful connection to database
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.280EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=mongoConnect | comp=Orion | msg=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[196]: Successful connection to database
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.281EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=mongoConnect | comp=Orion | msg=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[196]: Successful connection to database
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.282EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=mongoConnect | comp=Orion | msg=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[196]: Successful connection to database
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.282EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=mongoConnect | comp=Orion | msg=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[196]: Successful connection to database
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.283EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=mongoConnect | comp=Orion | msg=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[196]: Successful connection to database
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.283EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=mongoConnect | comp=Orion | msg=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[196]: Successful connection to database
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.284EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=mongoConnect | comp=Orion | msg=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[196]: Successful connection to database
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.284EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=mongoConnect | comp=Orion | msg=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[196]: Successful connection to database
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.285EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=mongoConnect | comp=Orion | msg=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[196]: Successful connection to database
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.285EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=mongoInit | comp=Orion | msg=contextBroker.cpp[1289]: Connected to mongo at localhost:orion
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.286EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=getOrionDatabases | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[283]: Database Operation Successful (listDatabases command)
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.286EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=subscriptionsTreat | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[2911]: Database Operation Successful ({})
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.287EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=subscriptionsTreat | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[2911]: Database Operation Successful ({})
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.288EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=treatOnTimeIntervalSubscriptions | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[553]: Database Operation Successful ({ conditions.type: "ONTIMEINTERVAL" })
time=2015-10-01T11:31:09.288EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=main | comp=Orion | msg=contextBroker.cpp[1597]: Startup completed
time=2015-10-01T11:31:18.112EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=1443713469-276-00000000001 | function=connectionTreat | comp=Orion | msg=rest.cpp[910]: Starting transaction from 127.0.0.1:45867/version
time=2015-10-01T11:31:18.114EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=1443713469-276-00000000001 | function=requestCompleted | comp=Orion | msg=rest.cpp[442]: Transaction ended
time=2015-10-01T11:31:19.289EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=getOrionDatabases | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[283]: Database Operation Successful (listDatabases command)
time=2015-10-01T11:31:19.290EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=subscriptionsTreat | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[2911]: Database Operation Successful ({})
time=2015-10-01T11:31:19.290EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=subscriptionsTreat | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[2911]: Database Operation Successful ({})
time=2015-10-01T11:31:29.292EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=getOrionDatabases | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[283]: Database Operation Successful (listDatabases command)
time=2015-10-01T11:31:29.293EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=subscriptionsTreat | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[2911]: Database Operation Successful ({})
time=2015-10-01T11:31:29.293EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=subscriptionsTreat | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[2911]: Database Operation Successful ({})
time=2015-10-01T11:31:39.294EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=getOrionDatabases | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[283]: Database Operation Successful (listDatabases command)
time=2015-10-01T11:31:39.295EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=subscriptionsTreat | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[2911]: Database Operation Successful ({})
time=2015-10-01T11:31:39.295EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | function=subscriptionsTreat | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[2911]: Database Operation Successful ({})
time=2015-10-01T11:31:39.427EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=1443713469-276-00000000002 | function=connectionTreat | comp=Orion | msg=rest.cpp[910]: Starting transaction from 188.***.**.***:58440/ngsi10/queryContext
time=2015-10-01T11:31:39.442EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=1443713469-276-00000000002 | function=entitiesQuery | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[1616]: Database Operation Successful ({ query: { $or: [ { _id.id: "entity_1" } ], _id.servicePath: { $in: [ null, /^$/, /^/.*/ ] } }, orderby: { creDate: 1 } })
time=2015-10-01T11:31:39.444EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=1443713469-276-00000000002 | function=registrationsQuery | comp=Orion | msg=MongoGlobal.cpp[2206]: Database Operation Successful ({ query: { $or: [ { contextRegistration.entities: { $in: [] } }, { contextRegistration.entities.id: { $in: [ "entity_1" ] } } ], expiration: { $gt: 1443713499 }, servicePath: { $in: [ null, /^$/, /^/.*/ ] } }, orderby: { _id: 1 } })
time=2015-10-01T11:31:39.453EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=1443713469-276-00000000002 | function=requestCompleted | comp=Orion | msg=rest.cpp[442]: Transaction ended
```

Comment: Is there a regular pattern in the sucess-fail secuence? I mean, the first one is ok, the second fail, the third is ok, the fourth fail, the firth is ok, the sixth fails, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's exacly how it goes.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a screenshot of that behaviour.

Comment: The problem you have seems to be the same than the one described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840739/orion-context-broker-works-half-of-the-times. Please, have a look in order the solution explained there works for you (in which case, a +1 is welcome ;)

Comment: I checked that question and preformed the alterations sugested but it did not work. Do you have any more sugestions?

Comment: There is also a questions reported with a similar problem that happens when Orion runs along with Tomcat  (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615073/orion-has-issues-running-alongside-apache-tomcat-7). Is that your case?

Comment: I've already checked that one :) i don't have Tomcat installed either so that can't be the problem!

Comment: Could you restart Orion with full trace level (`-t 0-255`) and check if the request that fail generate traces in the log file, please?

Comment: Answer edited to include the ContextBroker logs.

Comment: Let's try another simple test... use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in the curl command and see what it happens, please.

Comment: I tried putting 127.0.0.1 like you sugested but te results are the same.

Comment: In order to focus in the problem, could you restrict the log to only the part related with the version test, please? I mean, avoiding all the init messages ("Successful connection to database"). Please use `-t 0-255` (to ensure higer logging level) and `-subCacheIval 0` (to avoid "noise" of the cache refresh thread in the log). You should see traces such as `Starting transaction from A.B.C.D:NNNN/version` and `Transaction ended`.

Comment: In addition, add the `-v` option to the curl command (just in case the verbose mode provides some extra useful information)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91185/discussion-between-fgalan-and-diogo-nunes).

Comment: An issue has been created in Orion repository about this: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as refered on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615073/orion-has-issues-running-alongside-apache-tomcat-7) post's answer, there is a RAM memory issue regarding this problem. In fact my VM was running low on memory after a lot of testing and that itself made the Context Broker have this problem. I freed the memory and now the issue is gone.